# UITextView can not scroll to bottom when make a new line

Tags: ios, uikit, uitextview

when i texting in a textview at the text's end ,when the textview decides to make a newline to write , it seems that the textview will automatically set the contentoffset to make the last line to be visible (not the textview's bottom to visible, just the last line of text to visible), 
[image]

but if i want to make the textview scroll to bottom like this , how to achieve this nicely?
[image]

**added**

the things i want is make a textView like textView in iPhone's 'Message' App. and now the only difference between my version and the Message's is that my TextView will scroll to the last line to be visible , and the TextView is 'Message' will scroll to the bottom , and i want to do the same as it

Answer (score 0):

I think you could achieve this by setting `contentInset`, for example

```
self.textView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 10, 0);
```

This will increase the padding between the last line and the bottom.

Comment: thanks ,but it seems not work , in fact , the things i want most  is kinda like replace the default behavior of textview when insert a new line

Comment: It seems to be hard to do that though. Maybe should think about another way to define that behaviour from UX point of view rather than try to override the system behavior.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly......

You can always add "\n" to the end of text string which gives you the last empty line.

Use `UITextViewDelegate` methods to manage to add or remove or check "\n" while typing.

Comment: -_-,i know my description is hard to understand , the things i want is make a textView like textView in iPhone's 'Message' App. and now the only difference between my version and the Message's is that my TextView will scroll to the last line to be visible  , and the TextView is 'Message' will scroll to the bottom , and i want to do the same as it :)

Comment: @ximmyxiao Try to add "\n" in the end of string, it will give you a empty line on the bottom. But if you are doing complicated UI, I would suggest use UIScrollView or UITableView to do so.